# how can I use fadeTo inside $(element).each(...)

Tags: jquery, loops

I have some divs and I want to use each method of jquery to loop through the divs and want to apply an effect individually on each div, one after one. To be more clear I want to fade a dive to 0.5 (opacity) then delay(300) then again fadeTo back 1 (opacity) but I want each div to do so one after one. Can anyone please show me the proper way. Thanks.

[**Code is in a fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/NHdB6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = $('.box');
var i = 0;
LoadSequence();

//recursive for all the items.
function LoadSequence() {
    obj.eq(i++).fadeTo('1000', 0.1).delay(300).fadeTo('1000', 1, LoadSequence);
};
​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NHdB6/6/

Comment: Would be slightly nicer if you pass `obj` and `i` as parameters to `LoadSequence`.

Answer (score 1):

I made a lil' plugin a while ago. This might help:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/9Zxew/

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.fade1by1 = function (options) {
        var opt = $.extend({
                'delay' : 500,
                'speed' : 500,
                'ease' : 'swing' // Other requires easing plugin
            }, options);
        var that = this;
        for (var i = 0, d = 0, l = that.length; i < l; i++, d += opt.delay) {
            that.eq(i).delay(d).fadeIn(opt.speed, opt.ease);
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

I always think it's better to use animation completion functions rather than multiple different coordinated timers as it guarantees the sequential nature.  Here's how I'd do it:

```
function fadeElementsSequential(selector) {
    var elems$ = $(selector);
    var i = 0;
    function next() {
        if (i < elems$.length) {
            elems$.eq(i++).fadeTo(1000, 0.5).delay(300).fadeTo(1000, 1, next);
        }
    }
    next();
}

fadeElementsSequential(".box");
```

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/BW6YF/

Note: I changed the opacity values in the demo just to make it a little more visible.